# How do I implement a loading animation with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, lottie, loading-animation

I already have an animation made in AfterEffects that I think Lottie can turn into a format I can use for my app. What I am wondering is how can I make the app start performing this animation when it is opened until the app is done loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply show the animation view instead of your content view while it's loading

example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLoading = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isLoading {
                LoadingView()
            } else {
                DoneLoadingView()
            }
        }.onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoadingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProgressView()
    }
}

struct DoneLoadingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}
```